# Copying pixels from a mc with moving elements in it

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to copy pixels from a mc which has moving parts in it ( like a circle that moves from one corner of the mc to the other corner and repeats that infinitely), to another mc every second.

Yet it doesnt have only to copy them, it has to be processor/performance friendly, because i did find a way of doing that but it lags a lot.

my way was this:

```
    public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var myRainbow:Rainbow = new Rainbow();
    private var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    private var bmd:BitmapData;
    private var countainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap();

    public function Main()
    {
        this.addChild( mySprite );
        mySprite.addChild( myRainbow );
        mySprite.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5 - myRainbow.width * 0.5;
        mySprite.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5 - myRainbow.height * 0.5;

        bmd = new BitmapData( 50, 50 );
        bm.x = 0;
        bm.y = 0
        countainer.addChild( bm );
        addChild( countainer )
        countainer.x = 100
        countainer.y = 100

        countainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClick)
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    }

    private function onFrame( event:Event )
    {
        bmd.draw( mySprite, new Matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ), null, null, new Rectangle( 0, 0, 50, 50 ) );
        bm.bitmapData = bmd;
    }
    //dont mind the other methods.
}
```

where the class **Rainbow()** is actually the mc with the moving elements in it.

But when I test this code on a tablet with 4-5 elements that copy different pixels from the **Rainbow()** (or on a PC with 10-20 elements ) it starts to lag. Surely it is the copying of the pixels every frame but could`t find another solution.

So is there any other way of doing this? Im open for any suggestions. Hope you have came across this problem.

PS: 1: you can see what Im doing at this link: [Moving elements](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5u6hrR2w7UEYmFHbHdlWnlWNjA/edit)

PS: 2: the main MC (in my case is Rainbow) is going to be above 400x300 dimensions and those 4-5 elements will show different parts of the main mc but will show all the area( what i mean is that 1st mc will track the area from 0 to 100 in X dimension, 2nd from 100 to 200, 3rd from 200 to 300, 4th from 300 to the very end, and they`ll have a height of the main MC -> in this case 300)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29)

`copyPixels` is extremely fast on bitmaps. Your problem is that you are changing the bitmap every frame, which if done on multiple objects means that not only you draw the source, but you also create new bitmaps every frame.

Try copying pixels and be sure that you use the destination, which will directly put the bitmap onto the right place.

You can also try to lock the bitmap before drawing, which will also increase performance.

Comment: thanks a lot. I guess the **lock bitmap** is only for **.draw**. Is there something like that for the copyPixels -> somethink that will boost the performance even more?

Comment: Check out the reference. It says that *Locks an image so that any objects that reference the BitmapData object, such as Bitmap objects, are not updated when this BitmapData object changes.* It's exactly for setting those pixels. You can use it on both the bitmap that you draw the MovieClip into, as well as those that you copy the pixels to. Just lock everything and unlock it later - won't hurt :)

Comment: hmmm well it apparently it isnt as simple as i would like it to be :D. Because you need to transform the moving MC into bitmapData and then copy from it (or at least i understand it that way). Currently Im searching for the solution but if know this would love it if you help me :D @Andrey Popov

Comment: You've almost done it. Save a member variable for the BitmapData that will be drown from the mc. Each frame lock it and draw the mc onto it. DO NOT assign it to anything. You should have separate Bitmaps with BitmapData objects for each of the elements that you are talking about. Use element.copyPixels(source BitmapData, source area that you would like to copy); Then unlock all BitmapData's and the Bitmaps will be updated on the next key frame. Should work with just a few lines of code, that you haven't provided (elements).

Comment: Well .... still cant figure it out. Cant figure how to clone the data from the movingMC to another object without using the **.draw** method. Im still searching for it and trying different things but it starts to see to me pointless after so much time. I uploaded the code and the swf to a live platform ( where you write your code and it directly shows what you have done in the browser just right next to it) and also my attempts with **copyPixel** method are commented out there too -> the link is http://wonderfl.net/c/4qie/edit  If that helps @Andrey Popov.

Comment: ooohhh... now i understand. My problem was that I was trying to figure a method to replace the **.draw** and now I see that I didnt have to do that. Well thanks a lot : )) and the comments are really helpful. Thanks @Andrey Popov

Comment: Glad that helped! :) You could close the question so there are no unanswered questions left.. Cheers and good luck! :)